# Highcharts Annotation Position/Top Is Incorrect Upon Initial Rendering

Tags: javascript, highcharts

We are using the annotations module to add a annotation (image) to a area chart.  There is some strange 'top' calculations being done for the annotation that I can't exactly explain clearly.  We are passing in a `Distance` property (you'll see it in fiddle options) and highcharts is rendering it differently in different situations.

http://jsfiddle.net/jxpvrjta/13/

1. If you open a new window and paste in fiddle, you'll get a top of 310.
2. If you then click in the address bar and press Enter key to issue a GET again, the top 'fixes' itself and you will then have 297.

Try this without opening inspection window first and just notice the difference between x-axis and the annotation. I can't pinpoint the behavior exactly and when highcharts fixes the top rendering. Resizing the browser window fixes it sometimes. Sometimes, clicking the 'Run' button in fiddle fixes it.

I tried calling `.reflow()` on the chart as a solution but that doesn't seem to fix the problem either.

Comment: I see that you reported that issue on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/8373 Let's continue this topic there - it seems to be already known problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on GitHub issues [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7468#issuecomment-347904627).  Basically you have to put an inline style on the image providing height/width so that the annotations module can correctly calculate its size.  This resolved the issue for us.